# Bottom Navigation Tool Bar and Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin

I have two bottom navigation in my project. First Bottom Navigation is working and the second bottom navigation is not working and getting `ToolBar` must not be null error message. I am using `kotlin` language.  In one `BottomNavigationActivity`, I have one Activity and two fragments. I have attached the error message below and all the necessary libraries are imported. Any help is appreciated.

**Package Imported**

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

**Language Used**

```
Kotlin Language used.
```

**Code**

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        restoreSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test)
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        bottomNavigation = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        initBottomNavigation()
        initFragment(savedInstanceState)
    }
```

**Question**

```
ToolBar must not be null error message.
```

**Error**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: findViewById(R.id.toolbar) must not be null
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: findViewById(R.id.toolbar) must not be null
```

Comment: is there is toolbar in activity_test?

Comment: Thanks @DKV for your help. Your comment addressed this issue.

Comment: Does it solve the issue?.

Comment: Yes, @DKV. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Is it in your fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Below code addressed this issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:context="test"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont need use findViewById in kotlin. you can get id directly.

Comment: This should be comment.